# Render two components adjacent to each other in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am trying to call a component from another component to display some html and it works if I call the component alone, but if I add more markup inside the same return function, it throws the following error:

```
Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (9:12) while parsing file
```

Product.jsx

```
var React = require('react');

var Product = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<p>Product</p>);
    }
});

module.exports = Product;
```

ProductSlider.jsx (Works)

```
var React = require('react');
var Product = require('./Product.jsx');

var ProductSlider = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        return (
            <div><Product /></div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = ProductSlider;
```

ProductSlider.jsx (Doesn't Work)

```
var React = require('react');
var Product = require('./Product.jsx');

var ProductSlider = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        return (
            <div><Product /></div>
            <div><p>Something else</p></div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = ProductSlider;
```

Does anybody knows what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap a rendered component in a top level component, that's your problem. If you did

```
return (
      <div>
        <div><Product /></div>
        <div><p>Something else</p></div>
      </div>
    );
```

It would work.

Comment: Hi Ben! Thanks for your response. What am I doing different? If I write that code, it doesn't work, but if I remove the <div><p>Something else</p></div>, then it suddenly works.

Comment: You don't have that top level <div> that I added wrapping around the two innermost divs. React needs a top level DOM component to attach itself to, so it can't render it if you're rendering two DOM components as you were.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need a top level `<div>` wrapper**

If you are using react 16.2+. Simply use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
return(
  <Fragment> 
      <div><Product /></div>
      <div><p>Something else</p></div>
  </Fragment>
)
```

You can also try this way:

```
return(
  [
      <div key="unique1"><Product /></div>
      <div key="unique2"><p>Something else</p></div>
  ]
)
```

Note: `key` should be unique.